# Using and querying Custom Dimensions in Google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am attempting to query my Analytics (Universal) to receive a list of metrics sorted by a custom dimension.

In July, the [Google Analytics API blog](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/07/40-new-data-points-in-google-analytics.html) announced:

> "Developers can use custom dimensions to send unique IDs into Google Analytics, and then use the core reporting API to retrieve these IDs along with other Google Analytics data.
>
> For example, your content management system can pass a content ID as a custom dimension using the Google Analytics tracking code. **Developers can then use the API to get a list of the most popular content by ID and display the list of most popular content on their website.**"

Despite this, I have been unable to retrieve any results from my Analytics. My send function is below:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':'red'
});
```

Unfortunately, querying GA using a filter of 'ga:dimension1 == red' does not retrieve any results.

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
  'ids': 'ga:' + "123456",
  'start-date': '2013-11-10',
  'end-date': '2013-11-20',
  'metrics': 'ga:visits',
  'filters': 'ga:dimension1==red'
}).execute(function(r){console.log(r);});
```

I have also tried using custom segments to retrieve the data, to no avail:

```
'segment': 'dynamic::ga:dimension1==red'
```

The data appears in Custom Reports in GA. How can I access it via the API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include a the dimension in the query. Such as `'dimension': 'ga:dimension1'`, then use your filter `'ga:dimension1==red'`. The [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) is very helpful for testing API requests.

Comment: Just saved my life with that Query Explorer link, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

hey this is very helpful. thanks so much for the answer.
Let me also answer this question with an example:
let so for a ga defined dimension, the syntax would look like - ga:landingPagePath=="what ever you want"
now say there is a custom dimension called pagepath which is customdimension1 .
Hence the syntax will be ga:dimension1=="what ever you want"