# Google API analytics extraction permissions

Tags: api, permissions, analytics, google-analytics-api

Problem: cannot access Google Analytics View using API service (json credentials)

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Detail: When creating a Google analytics account via "Google Account A [analytics]" and creating an API service "Google Account A [developer console - JSON credentials] I can access Analytics data using the API.

I've been given access (Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyse, Manage Users ) to "Google Account B [Analytics]. Logged into a web browser I can access and see the GoogleAnalytics of Google Account B and have setup a 'Custom View' to access Custom dimensions.

- (GA A [Analytics] -> GA A [Dev console]) --- Access OK
- (GA B [Analtyics] -> GA A [Permission granted] -> GA A [Dev console]) --- Error

I am assuming if Google Account B created an API service and passed the credentials.json key file things would run smoothly. I want to use this as a last resort as the client will have no idea how to set this up.

I am looking for a reason (and solution to) why Google Account A can see the analytics view of (Google Account B) but the API service of Google Account A cannot access the view.

Original setup/testing: [Google Analytics UserID API extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756051/google-analytics-userid-api-extraction)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answer: A service account in Google API (that is created when setting up the API project) is associated with a user.
This particular user must also be granted access by the owning Google Analytics account.

> i.e. Service account xxxx.yyyy@googlepais.com that is created when
>   setting up a Google API service account.

Something sounds so simple but I was under the impression that since this account was created by a main Google account that already has access that these permissions were implicitly inherited... Not the case but kind of makes sense. And provides a lot more fine grained control.

Once this was granted the API extracted the correct information.